# Bind text to a selected drop down list value in angular 2

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular2-databinding

I have a drop down list in a *citylist* component template.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity.id">
 <option *ngFor="let cty of cityarray" [ngValue]= "cty.id"> 
    {{cty.name}}
 </option>
</select>
<p> </p> <!--selected city name -->
```

And the array of city is like this:

```
cityarray = [new Cities(1,'Berlin'),
          new Cities(2,'London'),
          new Cities(3,'Portland'),
          new Cities(4,'Zurich'),
          new Cities(5,'Cardiff') ]
```

where Cities class object has an *id* and a *name*.

What I want is to simply print the city selected from the drop down inside the para tags. 
If possible, How can this be done using **ngModel**? or do I have to write a model change event?

Comment: Have you already tried [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" and [ngValue]= "cty" ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XyDaCjlthy8N0QNmE2NM?p=preview

Comment: Easy-peasy @yurzui ! Perfect solution. Can you also tell how the '?' works?

Comment: You can think about it like  `someValue ? someValue.someProp : null` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up ngModelChange event like below:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity.id" (ngModelChange)="setCity($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let cty of cityarray" [ngValue]= "cty.id"> 
    {{cty.name}}
   </option>
</select>
<p>{{selectedCity}} </p>
```

**component**

```
selectedCity:any;
setCity($event){
 this.selectedCity = this.cityarray.filter(c => return c.id == $event)[0].name;
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Works fine for ngModelChange. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Odd way of doing this is :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity.id">
 <option *ngFor="let cty of cityarray" [ngValue]= "cty.id"> 
    {{cty.name}}
 </option>
</select>

<ng-container *ngFor="let cty of cityarray">
    <p *ngIf='selectedCity.id === cty.id'>
         {{cty.name}}
    </p>
</ng-container>
```